# How to use mapGetters with modules and root's getters at the same time?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I know how to use mapGetters in a single situation, but not both.

Example, I have `firstRootGetter` inside `store/index.js`, so I will call `...mapGetters(['firstRootGetter'])` in vue component.

If I have `firstModuleGetter` and `secondModuleGetter`inside `store/modules/post.js`, I will call `...mapGetters('post', ['firstModuleGetter', 'secondModuleGetter'])`

My question is, how do I call them in single `...mapGetters`. Is it possible?

Right now I have to write 2 lines to call them separately.

Comment: Are your modules namespaced?

Comment: @btl yes, it is namespaced.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you must supply the namespace to the `mapGetters` helper in each line, though:

```
...mapGetters({
  exampleGetter: 'myModule1/exampleGetter',
  anotherGetter: 'myModule2/anotherGetter',
})
```

If you're trying to combine them into a single getter, use a root `action` that reads both module stores and returns a combined object. Then `mapActions` like you would `mapGetters`.

Comment: Thank you but I don't ask for combining them into a single getter. I'm asking about how to use the `mapGetters`. In your answer, when I try to do: 
`...mapGetters([
 'firstRootGetter',
  'myModule1/exampleGetter',
  'myModule2/anotherGetter',
])`
it does not work.

Comment: See my answer again, I've edited how the getters are passed in. Use an object `{}` instead of an array `[]` and provide aliases for the getters. Doing this you can use `this.exampleGetter` and `this.anotherGetter`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Ta.

Comment: Oh are you real Linus Borg??? You are my idol! Back to the question, yes, of course, it worked in 2 getters, just wondering if I could make it in one place. Don't know why I like to call it at once. Again I'm really glad that you answer my question.

Answer (score 13):

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters('module1', ['getQuestions', 'getAnswers']),
        ...mapGetters('module2', ['getGrades'])
    },
```

This is the syntax used:

```
 ...mapGetters('some/nested/module', [
    'someGetter', // -> this.someGetter
    'someOtherGetter', // -> this.someOtherGetter
  ])
```